# How to change Firebug' font?

Tags: firefox, fonts, firebug

I liked my Firebug's font on FF3.6 . After installing FF4 and appropriate Firbug 1.7 font has changed. How can I chose font for Firebug?

Comment: seems more appropriate for programmers or superuser.

Comment: @nathan - Unless you're looking to modify the extension's code

Comment: @lwburk, true enough, though if this question is trying to ask that i would suggest the op rewrite it.

Comment: @nathangonzalez: not programmers.SE.  Possibly superuser, but you can ask questions about programming tools here.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem and have been looking for a while. I can't stand Courier. The solution is surprisingly simple:

1. In the Firefox Options -> Options -> Content -> (Fonts & Colors) Advanced -> Change the Monospaced font to the one you want
2. Restart Firefox

The side-effect is all websites that specify the monospace font will use the font you selected. This is ok for me, I don't have to see Courier.

Comment: Worked a charm for me, Consolas ftw!

Comment: This way you are going to change the default stylesheets which are very similar in all the browser, affecting the way you view the web. If it is ok, no problem at all, but if you develop, you may want to have such a configuration to test what you build for average users by assuming the same environment settings they have.

Comment: Never would have thought that firebug used browser's default font. Great solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can modify the css of the Firebug xpi

if you are using Mac OSX,the xip is at:
~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxx.default/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi

open it and modify the css file,change `font-family:Monaco, monospace;` to other.

or you can install the new **Firebug 1.8**(http://getfirebug.com/),it fixed the problem.

Comment: Got as far as turning the xpi into a zip, opening `firebug@software.joehewitt.com.zip\content\firebug\firebug.css`, but then I don't see Monaco anywhere.  Do you know which entry is the Script window?  And how does 1.8 solve the problem? In 1.11, I don't see an option for font.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to change the font from within Firefox/Firebug or under **about:config**, so you have to modify the plugin itself. There are a few things you'll need to do first, though. These instructions are valid as of the 1.8.3 version of Firebug.

*Note: These changes will disappear when Firebug is updated via Firefox.*

1. Remove the Firebug plugin in the Add-ons page. Restart Firefox and close the application.
2. The .xpi format is just a ZIP file, so download the xpi file and extract the file with your program of choice.

   http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.8/
3. Do a search and replace for the text **font-family: monospace;** and replace with your font choices. For example, I used **font-family: Consolas, "Lucida Console", monospace;**.

   ```
   \content\firebug\firebug.css
       Line 26:      font-family: monospace;
       Line 255:     font-family: monospace;
   \skin\classic\console.css
       Line 50:      font-family: monospace;
       Line 125:     font-family: monospace;
       Line 211:     font-family: monospace;
       Line 424:     font-family: monospace;
       Line 505:     font-family: monospace;
   \skin\classic\css.css
       Line 14:      font-family: monospace;
   \skin\classic\debugger.css
       Line 5:       font-family: monospace;
       Line 16:      font-family: monospace;
       Line 50:      font-family: monospace;
       Line 157:     font-family: monospace;
       Line 301:     font-family: monospace;
       Line 310:     font-family: monospace;
   \skin\classic\dom.css
       Line 156:     font-family: monospace;
   \skin\classic\firebug.css
       Line 72:      font-family: monospace;
       Line 81:      font-family: monospace;
       Line 92:      font-family: monospace;
       Line 497:     font-family: monospace;
   \skin\classic\html.css
       Line 11:      font-family: monospace;
       Line 76:      font-family: monospace;
   \skin\classic\net.css
       Line 245:     font-family: monospace;
       Line 655:     font-family: monospace;
   \skin\classic\panelbase.css
       Line 260:     font-family: monospace;
   \skin\classic\tableRep.css
       Line 4:       font-family: monospace;
   \skin\classic\win\firebug.css
       Line 151:     font-family: monospace;
   ```
4. Re-zip the files into a ZIP file with the same name as the one your downloaded.
5. Double-click the new extension file or install it from within Firefox.
6. Restart Firefox when prompted and your new monospace font will be used in the Firebug panels.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Firebug's area and press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Plus</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't change the font; it changes the *size* of the font.